# The connection was aborted exception while git push

Tags: git

why do we get " The connection was aborted" exception.... fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly .

The entire session reads:

```
vamshi.krishna@-KRISHNA /c/Project Repo/diameter (springdevelopment) $ git push origin springdevelopment 
vamshi.krishna@svn..local's password: 
Counting objects: 11, done. 
Delta compression using up to 4 threads. 
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done. 
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 3.06 KiB, done. 
Total 9 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) 
Read from remote host svn..local: The connection was aborted fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

Is it a connec tion issue? permission issue?

How to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there more to the error message? I bet there is.

Comment: vamshi.krishna@-KRISHNA /c/Project Repo/diameter (springdevelopment)
$ git push origin springdevelopment
vamshi.krishna@svn..local's password:
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 3.06 KiB, done.
Total 9 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Read from remote host svn..local: The connection was aborted
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your current branch using **git pull origin remore_branch_name**.